# Override html page template for a specific sphinx document

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm implementing a documentation using Sphinx (https://github.com/fridge-project/dbal-docs) & would like to override the html page of a specific document. My interest is to override all directory indexes to not only show a simple ul.

I have read the Sphinx documentation but I don't find something interesting about my issue... Does someone know a workaround?

Comment: Did you eventually find a solution?

Comment: Yes, I have found a solution but it really sounds like a hack...
I have overridden the `page.html` template & make some conditional check according to the `pagename` & then `include` custom template instead of the real one...

Comment: Could you paste the solution here? Would be helpful even if it's just a hack.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For the record, this solution is much more a hack than a solution but for now, I don't find something better...

First, of all you need to understand my workaround is based on the theming. In your doc, you use a theme (the default one or a custom one) but anyway, you use a theme. This theme is divided in different part (page, toc, ...) which can be individually overridden. This override can be done at different level: the theme itself or in the custom template directory of the project (by default `_templates`) (configurable in the `conf.py`).

My workaround is to override the `page.html` template in the `_templates` dir which represents all pages in your documentation. In this template, you have access to the `pagename` (relative doc path of each file). Knowing that, you can make some conditional check in this template to detect if this is a file you want to override & then override it. If it is not a file which need to be overridden, simply fallback on the default behavior:

```
{% extends "layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
    {% if pagename == 'index' %}
        {% include 'custom/index.html' %}
    {% else %}
        {{ body }}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

As explain, it really sounds like a hack...

Answer (score 8):

One should be able to use a variable to define the [template to extend from](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#template-objects).

In that way it might be less of a 'hack'. And you have full control about the generated output(not only the `body` block).

layout.html:

```
{% extends meta.page_template|default('basic/page.html') %}
```

And in your index.rst you use then [page-level metadata](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/markup/misc.html#file-wide-metadata):

index.rst:

```
:page_template: custom/index.html
<your normal index.rst content>
```