# In sphinx jinja2 template, get the path to current document

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

I'm building documentation with Sphinx and rST. The docs are internationalized and deployed to paths like this:

```
website.tld/en/index.html
website.tld/de/index.html
```

Now on each page I'd like to give a link to the same page in different languages. Current language is available as the `language` variable, and the list of all languages is explicitly added to the `html_context` and, thus, also available.

What I struggle with is the relative path to each document. Say, there's a source document at `./source/somepath/docname.rst`. It builds into these:

```
website.tld/en/somepath/docname.html
website.tld/de/somepath/docname.html
```

In the Jinja2 template, how do I get the `"somepath/docname.html"` value?

Answer (score 1):

Suddenly, I've found the solution in [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16368746/2790048) to a related question:

```
{{ pagename }}
```

For a source document at `./source/somepath/docname.rst`, the value of `pagename` is `"somepath/docname"`, which is quite what I need.

Here's [the documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/development/templating.html#pagename) for this variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pagename` together with `pathto` to generate href like this

```
{{ pathto('../de/', 1) }}{{ pagename }}.html
```

If you are currently on
`website.tld/en/somepath/docname.html`

This will expand to
`../../de/somepath/docname.html`